# Bers' simultaneous uniformization

Tags: cv.complex-variables, hyperbolic-geometry, teichmuller-theory, quasiconformal

I have been trying to understand Bers' famous paper "Simultaneous Uniformization". Regarding this paper I have a few questions. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Let $S$ and $S^{'}$ be two abstract Riemann surfaces and $f : S \rightarrow S^{'}$ a homeomorphism of bounded eccentricity (one can think it as a quasiconformal map, though QC maps are by definition orientation preserving but here $f$ can also be orientation reversing), and such a pair $(S, [f], S^{'})$ is called a coupled pair, where $[f]$ denotes the homotopy class of $f$. A coupled pair is called $\textit{odd}$ if $f$ is orientation reversing and $\textit{even}$ if it's orientation preserving. Now two coupled pairs $(S, [f], S^{'})$ and $(S_{1}, [f_{1}], S^{'}_{1})$  are said to be equivalent if there exist $\textbf{conformal homeomorphisms}$ $h$ and $h^{'}$ such that $h(S)=S_{1}$, $h^{'}(S^{'})=S^{'}_{1}$ and $[h^{'} \circ f \circ h^{-1}]=[f_{1}]$

$\textbf{Question 1 : }$ What does it mean to be a $\textbf{conformal homeomorphism}$ between two  abstract Riemann surfaces ?

Secondly, suppose $m$ is a Beltrami differential on a Riemann surface $S_{\circ}$, this Beltrami differential defines a metric on $S_{\circ}$, this metric in turn defines a conformal structure on $S_{\circ}$ and this in turn gives rise to a new complex structure (since there is a one-one correspondence between complex structures up to biholomorphism and conformal structures up to isometry),call the resulting Riemann surface $S_{\circ}^{m}$ . Hence we have a new even coupled pair $(S_{\circ}^{m}, [Id] , S_{\circ})$, where $[Id]$ is the homotopy class of the identity map and a odd coupled pair $(S_{\circ}^{m}, [\iota], \bar{S_{\circ}})$, where $\iota$ denotes the natural mapping of $S_{\circ}$ onto its mirror image $\bar{S_{\circ}}$.
$\bar{S_{\circ}}$ is defined by replacing each local uniformization $\xi$ on $S_{\circ}$ by $\bar{\xi}$.

$\textbf{Question 2 :}$ What is the explicit description of the map $\iota$ ?

$\textbf{Question 3 :}$ Suppose $(S,[f],S^{'})$ is an odd coupled pair. Then how one can show that this pair is equivalent (in the sense defined above) to one of the form $(S_{\circ}^{m}, [\iota], \bar{S_{\circ}})$ ? (One can assume that $S$ has hyperbolic universal cover)

Comment: The term *conformal homeomorphism* was popular at that time to mean *biholomorphism* of Riemann surfaces. It stresses the fact that biholomorphisms are closed under uniform convergence on compact sets.

Comment: Thanks @BenMcKay. Any comment on the other two questions?

Comment: From your description of the mirror image, it would surely seem that $\iota$ is, in the set-theoretic sense, simply the identity. As for Question 3, I guess you let $S_{\circ}$ be the mirror image of $S'$. Then $f^{-1}$ is a qc map from $S_{\circ}$ to $S$, and therefore $S$ is conformally equivalent to $S_{\circ}$ associated with the Beltrami differential obtained by pulling back the standard complex structure on $S$. Am I missing something?